# Get shopping cart details in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to get the shopping cart details, by using Magento's `getQuote` function. How can I do this?

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
```

When I print the `$cart` Page stops execution and blank page is shown.
 But when I write

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();
```

and print the `$cart` an array will show. But I want to track the complete cart data (product Id,Product price like all information).

Is there any other method by which I can find the shopping card data?

Answer (score 26):

The object returned by `getQuote` is a [`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Quote.html). It has a method [`getAllItems`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Quote.html#getAllItems) which in turn returns a collection of [`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item.html) objects.

All this means you can inspect products like this:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

PS. The reason you get a blank page is because dumping a whole object likely fell into recursion and the page timed out, or PHP ran out of memory. Using `getData` or `debug` is safer but, as you saw, doesn't return the protected/private variables.

Comment: The only thing to add here is installing xDebug makes it "safe" to drop an object into PHP var_dump function and avoid most recursion related problems.

Comment: Great one just a quick little fix it is: foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item)  instead of foreach ($cart->getItems() as $item) .

Comment: @mahdi If you know the cart ID then loading it works the same as all other models in Magento, `$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->load($id)`

Comment: i tried to use the method on top to check my shopping cart's Id, but every product's id appear as the same as the first item, why?

Comment: I am just staring with Magento.  In this context @clockworkgeek, is the cart id the same as the quote id? (i.e. in sales_flat_quote)

Comment: @OliverWilliams correct.  In memory the cart and quote are separate objects but they share the same ID.  The class `Mage_Checkout_Model_Resource_Cart` even uses the database table `sales_flat_quote` directly.

Comment: how to get all quoteid in .net soap api

Answer (score 2):

Get shopping cart items using **getQuote()** method

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cart->getData());
```

Get Shopping Cart items without **getQuote()** method

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItems();
echo "<pre>";print_r($cart->getData());
```