# How do I get in Magento the current order ID whlie on the products page?

Tags: magento

Im on the page showing the products I have avaliable in my Magento store. I want to get the current ID of the order should I continue on adding the order to my cart and buy it at the end.

Since the order per say does not exist and more than one person can buy at the same time, I would have to calculate the order ID someway while making sure that it does not conflict with another person making another order at the same time.

Another thing is like I mentioned that this is on the product listing page (/../../../../../template/catalog/product/list.phtml) so a "order" per say (I mentioned this before) does not exist.

How can I get the best possible way a order ID that is not in usage?

Comment: You get a quote id when you add a product to the cart. You get a order id after you start the checkout process (around payment info)

Comment: Is this quote id for EACH product or for the cart? It will be perfect for the cart.

Comment: The quote is is store in your cart session.. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625688/getquote-function-magento

Comment: That page only comments that it returns a array. Is the quote ID inside the array? How would I access it (unless it has a field named "qUoTe Id" or something similar which I do not know)? I need a string (at least) that is a unique identifier for each cart.

Answer (score 7):

In Magento,on creation on cart a quote object is created and for each item you add there is a quote_item object.

You can get the current quote id from session

```
$session        = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote_id       = $session->getQuoteId();
```

And subsequently load the sales_quote object

```
$item_quote     = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id);
```

By this you could access any attribute related to the quote table easily.

For the items in cart you can access by

```
$items_in_cart      = $quote->getAllItems();
```

And run this in a loop

```
foreach ($items_in_cart as $item) { 

  echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
  echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
  echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
  echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
  echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';

}
```

Hope this helps!
For more reference you can refer here 
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-quote-order-invoice-workflow/

Comment: The solution looks intresting and I added the code to my phtml page:

`<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $session        = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $quote_id       = $session->getQuoteId();
    $item_quote     = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id);`

I then try to print out $item_quote but it shows blank. So it seems it isnt working correctly...
    
?>

Comment: Is there an item in your cart?

Comment: try to echo the echo $quoteId =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId(); Does it print anything?

Comment: Like you commented if my cart is empty, `$quoteId =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId(); ` does not print anything. I would need to calculate what number it would generate if it had item. I need something to identify my cart and/or order.

Comment: Yes when the cart is initialized an entry goes in the table sales_flat_quote,where all information concerning the current quote is saved.And the info regarding the items added goes in sales_flat_quote_item,which you can access by creating an object of Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item).Hopefully this clears your doubt.

Comment: The information needed would be the id that would be inserted when that cart is initialized. More of getting the "cart id", would be knowing the next cart id.......

Comment: What is then "initialized" that is unique so I can get it and use it as a identifier?

Comment: 'More of getting the "cart id", would be knowing the next cart id.'-why do you need this?

Comment: Because when I add a item to a cart, its going to have a option which is basically a file name. There can be thousands of carts at a time so I have to make a unique file name for the option. My initial thought is something like:

sessionnumber_numberofcart_productid_currenttime_nameofoption

Literally it would be

23_20003435_90_1353212624_nameiintro 

The thing is that since I can have more than one client, that needs to be unique reason why I have cart id and session id. Thats why I need the cart id.

I can add more than one product with the same name. I proably need a counter as well but...

Comment: yes the cart id will always be unique for that quote session.

Comment: OK, but how do I get that unique cart id for that quote session? From what I understand, you refer to quote session as my "sesssionnumber" and the cart id is "numberofcart" for me. Is this correct? Maybe I am not explaining it correctly and I apoligize.

Comment: No cart id is not the "numberofcart" for you..it is an autoincrement number generated on every new instance of cart.So even if it is a guest user or a registered user,it generated a unique id for the current quote instance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/) to create a order, you can create a order and when you save your new order get the next id for order.

Comment: I dont really need to create a NEW one, as Magento automatically does this. I would need to some how identify my cart/order as unique.